# Error while Creating Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a stored procedure. Once I created it, it was successfully created. But it is not displaying in the list of stored procedures. I refreshed the list, but it is not appearing. I also tried to recreate it, but there was an error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spProducts_DeleteProduct, Line 6
>   There is already an object named 'spProducts_DeleteProduct' in the database.

[image]

What is the reason behind not seeing that stored procedure in the list?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create the procedure in the master DB is that your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `ALTER PROCEDURE` to change a stored procedure definition. See docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-procedure-transact-sql).

You also need to make sure you're using the correct database. I bet if you look in master, it'll be there.

In the meantime, put `USE [YourDatabaseName]` at the top of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Drop procedure you created and try

```
use [Database]
Go
Create procedure  spProducts_DeleteProduct
```

Hope it works.